# MP4Box set both init and segment-name?

Tags: video, mp4box

I want to specify my segment names as such:

```
$RepresentationID$/segment_$Number$.m4s
```

and my Init file as `$RepresentationID$/play.mp4`

I have tried these:

This generates segments (init value will be segment_.m4s)

```
mp4box -dash 4000 -segment-name $RepresentationID$/segment_$Number$.m4s -out play.mpd -profile dashavc264:live -segment-ext null -mpd-title "" -mpd-info-url "" /full/path/dashify_file.mp4:id="video_hd"
```

I figured I wanted to rename init file to init.mp4

According to:

https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/dash/

I can use $Init=play.mp4$ like so

```
mp4box -dash 4000 -segment-name $RepresentationID$/$Init=play.mp4$ -out play.mpd -profile dashavc264:live -segment-ext null -mpd-title "" -mpd-info-url "" /full/path/dashify_file.mp4:id="video_hd"
```

But then the segments is just named 1-118

There is no info on combining these even if I type mp4box -h dash.

What I want to achieve is play.mp4 and the segments segment_%d.m4s inside the folder video_hd

The segmentation already works great so I don't need help with that, but I think it's kind of ugly with the init file being called segment_.m4s

I have been struggling with this for long, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported, but it will be a feature added later:

https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues/458